# Insert new row on group_by data in R dplyr based on condition

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

Here is example dataset:

```
example = data.frame(
          bucket = c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1),
          bucket2 = c(0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4),
          rate = c(0.95,0.02,0.01,0.005,0,0.9,0.05,0.02,0.01,0))
```

And I would need sum of rate by bucket to be 1. Currently, it is not equal to 1.

```
example %>% group_by(bucket) %>% summarise(sum(rate))
```

Therefore, I need a way to insert a new row with a rate to make sum of rate grouping by bucket to always be 1. For this example, I would need to insert 2 new rows as below:

```
new_rows = data.frame(bucket = c(0,1), 
                      bucket2 = c('To make 0','To make 0'),
                      rate = c(0.015,0.02))
```

The real dataset is much bigger with more groups, but the problem is still how do I create new row based on my conditions using dplyr or other packages? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have almost achieved what you want.

```
new_rows <- example %>%
            group_by(bucket) %>%
            summarise(rate = 1 - sum(rate))

new_rows

#   bucket  rate
#    <dbl> <dbl>
# 1      0 0.015
# 2      1 0.02

bind_rows(example, new_rows)

#    bucket bucket2  rate
# 1       0       0 0.950
# 2       0       1 0.020
# 3       0       2 0.010
# 4       0       3 0.005
# 5       0       4 0.000
# 6       1       0 0.900
# 7       1       1 0.050
# 8       1       2 0.020
# 9       1       3 0.010
# 10      1       4 0.000
# 11      0      NA 0.015
# 12      1      NA 0.020
```

Comment: I suggest adding `%>% filter(rate > 0)` to `new_rows` after `summarize`.

Comment: You can also transform it to a one-liner: `bind_rows(example, example %>% group_by(bucket) %>% summarise(rate = 1-sum(rate)))`.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, adding rows needs `bind_rows`. Doing something per-group (outside of the normal `dplyr` verbs, though notably not `bind_rows`) requires a `do` block. I'm inferring what you need for the columns, but you can adapt the premise to whatever else.

```
example2 <- example %>%
  group_by(bucket) %>%
  do(bind_rows(., data_frame(bucket = .$bucket[1], bucket2 = max(.$bucket2)+1, rate = 1-sum(.$rate))))
example2
# # A tibble: 12 x 3
# # Groups:   bucket [2]
#    bucket bucket2  rate
#     <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
#  1      0       0 0.95 
#  2      0       1 0.02 
#  3      0       2 0.01 
#  4      0       3 0.005
#  5      0       4 0    
#  6      0       5 0.015
#  7      1       0 0.9  
#  8      1       1 0.05 
#  9      1       2 0.02 
# 10      1       3 0.01 
# 11      1       4 0    
# 12      1       5 0.02 
example2 %>% group_by(bucket) %>% summarise(sum(rate))
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   bucket `sum(rate)`
#    <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1      0           1
# 2      1           1
```

If the calculations for each group are more complicated, realize that the more row-verbose version of this is something like:

```
  ... %>%
  do({
    x <- .
    # more calcs feasible here, it's just an R block
    data_frame(
      bucket  = x$bucket[1],
      bucket2 = max(x$bucket2) + 1,
      rate    = 1 - sum(x$rate)
    )
  })
```